# Reverse Geocode - return locality

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm having trouble returning a city using reverse geocoding in Objective C on iOS. I'm able to log the city within the completionHandler, but I can't seem to figure out how to return it as a string if it's called from another function.

The city variable is an NSString created in the header file.

```
- (NSString *)findCityOfLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{

    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if ([placemarks count])
        {

            placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

            city = placemark.locality;

        }
    }];

    return city;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your design is incorrect.

You cannot synchronously return a value in your method, since you're performing an asynchronous call.

The `completionHandler` is a block that will be called somewhen in the future, so you have to change the structure of your code to handle the result when the block is called.

For instance you can use a callback:

```
- (void)findCityOfLocation:(CLLocation *)location { 
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self; // Don't pass strong references of self inside blocks
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error || placemarks.count == 0) {
           [weakSelf didFailFindingPlacemarkWithError:error]; 
        } else {
            placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            [weakSelf didFindPlacemark:placemark];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)didFindPlacemark:(CLPlacemark *)placemark {
     // do stuff here...
}

- (void)didFailFindingPlacemarkWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // handle error here...
}
```

Or a block (which I usually prefer)

```
- (void)findCityOfLocation:(CLLocation *)location completionHandler:(void (^)(CLPlacemark * placemark))completionHandler failureHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureHandler { 
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (failureHandler && (error || placemarks.count == 0)) {
           failureHandler(error);
        } else {
            placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            if(completionHandler)
                completionHandler(placemark);
        }
    }];
}

//usage
- (void)foo {
   CLLocation * location = // ... whatever
   [self findCityOfLocation:location completionHandler:^(CLPlacemark * placemark) {
        // do stuff here...
   } failureHandler:^(NSError * error) {
        // handle error here...
   }];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Even though you cannot up vote the answer, you can accept it by selecting the tick under the score ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know could only check off a single answer. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

The reverse geocoding request happens asynchronously, meaning the `findCityOfLocation` method will return before the completionHandler processes the response. I would suggest that you don't rely on the city being returned in the `findCityOfLocation` method, but just perform whatever action you want with the city from within the completionHandler:

```
- (void)findCityOfLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{

    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if ([placemarks count])
        {

            placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

            weakSelf.city = placemark.locality;

            // we have the city, no let's do something with it
            [weakSelf doSomethingWithOurNewCity];
        }
    }];    
}
```